# undefined when returning the query results from sqlite storage in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, react-native

I'm trying to return the results of the query but I always get undefined. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using react native with sqlite storage plugin.

```
let SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
let db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "db.v1.33", createFromLocation : "~db.db"});
let sqlResults;

export function GetQuestions(sqlType,questionsCount) {
    let sqlQuestions = `SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Type IN (${sqlType}) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT ${questionsCount}`

    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(sqlQuestions, [], (tx, results) => {
            sqlSize = results.rows.length;
            sqlResults = results;
        });
    });

    return sqlResults;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is that `db.transaction` is asynchronous, which means that it takes some time to do while the rest of the code moves on. So, `db.transaction` is started and then it immediately returns the `sqlResults` variable, which has not yet been set. What you need to do is return either a promise (quick tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) or set make your modifications in the callback (of `tx.executeSql`). Only then is the result set and usable.